# How to call Alexa externally?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have set up an Echo Dot device for my account. My intent is to call an Alexa skill on this device externally.

I have seen a lot of tutorials, but I could only see that these skills were started by voice.

Is there any way to trigger an Alexa skill by using an API, and not using voice at all? If not, what would be the market available alternatives for such a workflow?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible yet to trigger Alexa directly without Alexa wasn't asked. You could use notifications. Alexa will have a yellow ring and user has to ask for messages.

See https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html for details.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way of achieving this.

By using IFTTT, there is a skill called IFTTTriger that you can install in your Alexa device, and later on, install the https://mkzense.com/iftttrigger .  In that way, I was able to create an IFTTT applet that could trigger Alexa using a virtual device.

That is the only way available as of now. Worked perfectly well.